# Show result from Two collection and apply filter on that result data

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a situation where i need to display combined data from two collections. After displaying that result data i want to apply filter on this result data.

Can anyone suggest way or can show example of this flow?
Here is my data with out put

## User

```
{ 
    "_id" : "a6s54fas46456",
    "studentId" : "qYt5yHiZfbGrvXWak",
    "name" : "name1"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "asdf46asd4f", 
    "studentId" : "e2r4nTRiZZRsX6Xgu",
    "name" : "name2"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "asdf463443asd4f", 
    "studentId" : null,
    "name" : "name3"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "a6s54fas42346456", 
    "studentId" : "qYt5yHiZfbGrvXWak",
    "name" : "name4"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "asdf46asd6542344f", 
    "studentId" : null,
    "name" : "name3"
}
```

## Student

```
{ 
    "_id" : "e2r4nTRiZZRsX6Xgu", 
    "studentName" : "student2"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "qYt5yHiZfbGrvXWak", 
    "studentName" : "student1"
}
```

## OutPut

```
{
UserId: a6s54fas46456
StudentId : "qYt5yHiZfbGrvXWak"
"name" : "name1"
"studentName" : "student1"
}
{
UserId: asdf46asd4f
StudentId : "e2r4nTRiZZRsX6Xgu"
"name" : "name2"
"studentName" : "student1"
}
{
UserId: asdf463443asd4f
StudentId : null
"name" : "name3"
"studentName" : null
}
{
UserId: a6s54fas42346456
StudentId : "qYt5yHiZfbGrvXWak"
"name" : "name4"
"studentName" : "student1"
}
{
UserId: asdf46asd6542344f
StudentId : null
"name" : "name3"
"studentName" : null
}
```

Thanks

Comment: share your collections.

Answer (score 1):

to get data from two collection you should use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)  and [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) with `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true:true`

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$lookup:{from:"students", localField:"studentId", foreignField:"_id", as:"student"}},
    {$unwind:{path:"$student",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}},
    {$project:{
        "UserId":"$_id",
        "StudentId" : "$student._id",
        "name" : 1,
        "studentName" : "$student.studentName"
        }
    }
])
```